# Frozen while booting, Nouveau system freeze fifo

Tags: boot, 22.04, startup

To explain better, I took some pictures:

```
 linux  archer  ~  dkms status
nvidia/520.56.06, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.38, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed


OS              Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel          5.15.0-52-generic
DE: GNOME 42.5 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11300H (8) @
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile
Memory: 3173MiB / 15795MiB
```

[image]

It is stuck here and when I press the power button, it shows me this:

[image]

Then I press longer to shut down. I do this two or three times and finally, after that, I am able to see login screen.

I saw that it might be because of NVDIA driver.
I don't know:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem today on a laptop very similar to yours (Acer Nitro 5 but on Ubuntu 20.04). Some things that helped me solve my problem:

### Possible solution 1

After a few hours, I noticed that my primary monitor (the laptop screen was remaining black) but my secondary monitor worked fine when I plugged it in.
I don't know if it will work, but it's a very easy check, so start here.

### Possible solution 2

I suspect the problem is related to `Xorg`:

1. In grub (when you choose which operating system to boot), choose *Advanced options for Ubuntu*
2. From the next menu, choose the Ubuntu version that ends with *(recovery mode)*
3. Instead of the login, you will get a menu with a purple background—choose *root*, which works like your terminal **but with sudo privileges**
4. Remove the X11 configuration (it will be created on reboot): `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
5. Reboot by typing `reboot`

### Possible solution 3

Type `dkms status`, to confirm that you have an Nvidia driver installed.
I tried toying around with different Nvidia drivers, and ended up with 515 (520 is the latest, at least for my GPU).
My output says: `nvidia, 515.65.01, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed`.

### Possible solution 4

This one didn't work for me, but you could try booting with a different kernel.
Plenty of people had problems with a bug in kernel `5.15.0-52-generic`, your kernel.
`5.15.0-48-generic` might work.

---

As a temporary fix, you could `sudo prime-select intel`, which let me log in, at least.
However, my laptop ran very slow (because it wasn't using the Nvidia GPU).
To revert, `sudo prime-select nvidia`.

Let me know what works and what doesn't.
I'm not very good at this stuff, but I'll help in any way I can.

Comment: About Xorg, as seen from the attached image(the last one), I changed the first one. It kinda solved, no more stuck in the bootup, but it comes really late. I don't know, I think I will switch to a more stable distro. I am having problems with Ubuntu.

Comment: In the last image, you're changing the driver, not removing the Xorg file!

Comment: Ok then, let's try it. 

`I suspect the problem is related to Xorg. Start in recovery mode (let me know if you don't know how), go to tty2 (CTRL+ALT+F2), and log in. Then, cd /etc/X11, rm xorg.conf (or cp xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original xorg.conf) and reboot. I suggest removing xorg.conf—it will be recreated on reboot and remove.`

Can you explain this more please?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detailed instructions. If that doesn't work, show me the output of `dkms status` please.